# failsafe plugin won't run on one project but will run on another -- why?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-failsafe-plugin

This is driving me insane. The Maven failsafe plugin will not run on my project. If I run `mvn verify` only surefire runs. If I type `mvn failsafe:verify` it fails with the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Simulation Experiment Server 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.11:verify (default-cli) @ experiment-server ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: C:\IdeaProjects\experiment_server\target\failsafe-reports
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.551s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 30 11:24:58 GMT-06:00 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.11:verify (default-cli) on project experiment-server: C:\IdeaProjects\experiment_server\target\failsafe-reports\failsafe-summary.xml (The system cannot find the path specified) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

It's complaining about not finding `failsafe-summary.xml`. But this should be created by the plugin. And the plugin works fine (and creates the `failsafe-summary.xml` file if I run  run Antonio Goncalves wonderful [Arquillian example project](http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/wytiwyr-what-you-test-is-what-you-run/).

So I copied the exact plugin information Antonio uses, and it still won't run on my project. I've modelled my POM to be exactly like his (except without a parent pom) -- something must be going wrong, I just don't know what. Why will failsafe run on his project but not mine??

Here is my failsafe pom.xml entry, which is taken right from his, and is the same as the one on the failsafe usaages site):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.maven.failsafe.plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Thanks for any help, this is driving me insane.

**UPDATE** Okay, I seem to have gotten the `cannot find failsafe-summary.xml` problem fixed -- I change my directory from `experiment_server` to `experiment-server`. I guess that messes up failsafe.

But, I'm still having trouble getting failsafe to run from the command `mvn verify` or `mvn integration-test`. Both those commands call surefire instead of failsafe.  I can now run failsafe directly by using the command: `mvn failsafe:integration-test`, but shouldn't failsafe automatically run with `mvn verify`?  My `mvn help:effective-pom` shows that failsafe is there, so that's not the problem... Any ideas?

Comment: Which Maven version do you run?

Comment: Can add an output of a run where the IT are not running? How did you call Maven ?

Comment: I run Maven 3.04. I don't understand what you are asking in your second question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: For the record, the `cannot find failsafe-summary.xml` problem is **not** due to a directory name issue but to the absence of the `integration-test` goal/phase binding.

Comment: David you should answer the question since yours is the correct solution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the [failsafe docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) for the test names `failsafe` expects by default:

```
<includes>
  <include>**/IT*.java</include>
  <include>**/*IT.java</include>
  <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

Are your tests named following one of these patterns?  If not, try defining the `<includes>` element in the plugin configuration.  Or change your test name(s) to fit the default pattern.

---

Okay, now that we've verified the test class names - typically when I add executions to plugin config I do it something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.maven.failsafe.plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>failsafe-verify</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This explicitly binds the `failsafe` plugin goals you want to run to the correct phases of the build lifecycle.  I believe the `surefire` plugin is bound to the `test` lifecycle phase by default (for a jar, war, & ejb anyway), but nothing is bound to `integration-test` or `verify`.

Comment: Yep, my integration tests are named foobarIT.java. I've even tried explicitly putting the `includes` in (and did it again now, just in case). The problem now isn't that failsafe doesn't find my tests -- it does, when I run `mvn failsafe:integration-test`.  The problem is when I run `mvn verify` or `mvn integration-test` failsafe isn't called, surefire is.

Comment: And that did it!  I wonder why just `<goal>integration-test</goal>` didn't work before.  Weird. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here I will share my 2 cents.  I had same issue and solution above didn't solve my problem.

I had maven-failsafe-plugin encapsulated in **pluginManagement** tag.  I noticed to move it out into **plugins** tag instead when I saw this doc in the 4.0.0 maven schema:

> Default plugin information to be made available for reference by
>   projects derived from this one. This plugin   configuration will not
>   be resolved or bound to the lifecycle unless referenced. Any local
>   configuration for a given plugin   will override the plugin's entire
>   definition here.

Hopefully this additional info. solves more ppl's problem like myself.

Comment: Incidentally, this guarantee is sometimes violated. For example, if you define the jRebel plugin in a parent pom's pluginManagement section, the jRebel maven plugin will run on every sub-project, even if it is not explicitly added to that sub-project's plugin definition. So, beware.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked only after I added the "default" includes.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/IT*.java</include>
                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
                <include>**/IntegrationTest*.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>failsafe-verify</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running 2.12.2 version of the failsafe plugin, this is normal. Switch to a previous version. It seem 2.13 is not available yet.

[Jira link](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-901?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)