# maven-failsafe-plugin not seeing my tests (seleniumHQ)

Tags: maven, selenium, maven-failsafe-plugin

i'm writing tests via selenium web driver here's my code :

Pom.xml

```xml
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SeleniumebDriverProject</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.11</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Skip the normal tests, we'll run them in the integration-test phase-->
                    <skip>false</skip> 
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution> 
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins> 
    </build>
</project>
```

My test class named GoogleTest.java.
after reading this post : [failsafe plugin won't run on one project but will run on another -- why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947701/failsafe-plugin-wont-run-on-one-project-but-will-run-on-another-why)

I changed the name of my class so it's:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Skip the normal tests, we'll run them in the integration-test phase-->
        <skip>false</skip> 
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    <executions>
</plugin>
```

But the problem persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/plugin-info.html) is named *integration-test* instead of *test*. Furthermore if you changed your naming convention to the convention of maven-failsafe-plugin than you don't need any configuration which includes etc. files. Just use the defaults.
Furthermore i assume you have started running the integration tests via:

```
mvn verify
```

Comment: i tried the default configuration and it works fine but when i tried to use another one heres the code :                      <executions>

        
   <execution>
   <phase>integration-test</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>test</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <skip>false</skip>
    <includes>
     <include>**/*IT.java</include>
    </includes>
   </configuration>
  </execution> 
 </executions>

Comment: i tried to test it with mvn verify and mvn integration-test and i'm getting errors :  [ERROR] Could not find goal 'test' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.11 among available goals verify, help, integration-test -> [Help 1]

Comment: As i wrote in my answer you need to change the configuration <goals><goal>test</goal></goals> into <goals><goal>integration-test</goal></goals>