# maven-failsafe-plugin Failures and BUILD SUCCESS?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I want to use maven-failsafe-plugin to run some integration tests. If any test fails, I want Maven to fail the build and not BUILD SUCCESS.

```
Tests run: 103, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 26
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS*
```

how can I configure it, that build not success is?

My failsafe plugin is configured as:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${failsafe.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
            <CI_INTEGRATION_OVERRIDE_PATH>${basedir}/..</CI_INTEGRATION_OVERRIDE_PATH>
        </systemProperties>
        <includes>
            <include>**/integration/**/*.java</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/integration/**/*TestSuite.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Which version of maven-failsafe-plugin do you use? Which Maven version? How did you called mvn to run integration tests?

Comment: See [this mail thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Failing-a-build-with-maven-failsafe-plugin-td3199308.html) on "Maven - Users".

Comment: MAVEN CALL: mvn clean install -P jars failsafe:integration-test -e
<failsafe.version>2.12</failsafe.version>
MAVEN 3.16

Comment: If i call mvn `failsafe:verify` then throws an error `cannot find failsafe-summary.xml`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solution.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unit-test</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <skip>false</skip>
          <enableAssertions>false</enableAssertions>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
          </includes>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <integration>${integration}</integration>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This answer is replacing the failsafe plugin with the surefire plugin.

Comment: If your integration testing doesn't require pre- and post- phases (set up and tear down) then use `surefire` - if you want to stop a server or delete a database, you shouldn't use a plugin that will fail since the `post-integration-test` phase then won't fire.

Comment: The question is how to make failsafe-plugin fail the build if there are test failures. "use surefire instead" does not answer the question.

Answer (score 20):

As Andrew pointed out, the correct solution is to use failsafe as intended. The integration-test goal is specifically designed not to fail the build. If you want to fail the build, call `mvn verify` or `mvn failsafe:verify`

For the `verify` goal to work, it needs to read the results of the integration test which by default are written to `${project.build.directory}/failsafe-reports/failsafe-summary.xml` so make sure that is getting generated.

Also, you have to make sure you bind your `maven-failsafe-plugin` configuration to both the `integration-test` goal and the `verify` goal in the `executions` part.

Failure to add either of those will lead to maven succeeding the build instead of failing it when integration tests fail.

Comment: I do agree with your answer. The it-test goal is by design doesn't fail. "My goals were different and I wanted to make an opinionated piece of software and I preferred the notion of convention over configuration." as quoted by Jason van Zyl in the history of maven article. It is always good to follow the conventions rather than hacking around to do stuff which it is not designed for.

Comment: I often find that the intents of the Maven authors appear to directly contradict the way a sane person might attempt to use it.

Comment: `mvn verify` will succeed even if the integration tests fail - `Tests run: 5, Failures: 1` --> `BUILD SUCCESS`. If you remove your last sentence, I'll remove my down-vote.

Comment: Ben I discovered how it works. The `maven-failsafe-plugin` must have the `summary-file` parameter in its config in order for the `mvn verify` phase to fail - so you were mostly correct but lacked a key detail. I'll edit your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running `mvn clean install` both the `integration-test` and `verify` phases should be executing.  According to the failsafe plugin docs the `failsafe:integration-test` and `failsafe:verify` goals are bound to those phases, so I don't believe the extra call to `failsafe:integration-test` is required.

That said however, I'm not sure I trust the failsafe plugin documentation.  I [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949341/944849) for someone earlier this year.  It turned out he had to explicitly bind each goal to the correct phase and then failsafe worked as expected.  Might be worth a shot.

Comment: I have found a solution, i can use maven-surefire-plugin for my integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Jenkins builds.

- Running the tests locally resulted in failed tests and thus failed build
- Running the tests on Jenkins resulted in failed tests but "BUILD SUCCESS"

**Solution:** in job configuration set `MAVEN_OPTS` to `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false`.

Jenkins by default seems to [ignore failed integration tests](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-24655).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/28684048/4412885