# maven-failsafe-plugin Errors and BUILD SUCCESS?

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

my question is very similar to this one: [maven-failsafe-plugin Failures and BUILD SUCCESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279160/maven-failsafe-plugin-failures-and-build-success)

and I manage to set up failsafe plugin to fail if tests fail.

But if test goes into error state, failsafe plugin still does not break the build.

```
.................
-------------------------------------------------------
   T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running xxxxx.IntegrationTierFunctionalTestCase
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.054 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error:
  testException(xxxxx.IntegrationTierFunctionalTestCas

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is
[INFO] [failsafe:verify {execution: functional-test-1024}]
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: C:\projects\oec-integration-server\trunk\oec-integrati
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is
[INFO] [failsafe:integration-test {execution: functional-test-24}]
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: C:\projects\oec-integration-server\trunk\oec-integrati
.............
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 58 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue May 28 17:48:13 BST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 114M/781M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

for simplicy IntegrationTierFunctionalTestCase  contains only this code

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
public class IntegrationTierFunctionalTestCase 
{

    @Test
    public void testException(){
        //fail();
        throw new RuntimeException("super error");
    }
}
```

if I uncomment fail() whole build fails correctly, with build failed.
but if I just throw an exception, it fails as on shown above.

oour plugin configuration looks like this

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <oec.env>TEST</oec.env>
            <mule.test.timeoutSecs>2400</mule.test.timeoutSecs>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
        <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/src/main/resources/config</additionalClasspathElement>
            </additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>functional-test-1024</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/IntegrationTierFunctionalTestCase.java</include>
                </includes>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx1024M</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What am I missing?
And no I do not want to wrap it in try-catch blocks and fail tests manually.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need having two executions blocks, cause the verify goal of the maven-failsafe-plugin is intended to check the results of the integration tests.

```
  <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>functional-test-1024</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/IntegrationTierFunctionalTestCase.java</include>
            </includes>
            <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx1024M</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>verify</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
```

Furthermore you should update the version of the maven-failsafe-plugin to 2.14.1 instead of 2.7.
**Update:** In the meantime update to [2.17](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/).

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked, but not in 2.7, so I had to update version as you mentioned

Comment: As pointed out in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279160/maven-failsafe-plugin-failures-and-build-success) - "the correct solution is to use failsafe as intended. The integration-test goal is specifically designed not to fail the build." Therefore although this information is correct, it is not the answer to the question.

Comment: The documentation at https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html currently recommends to use both goals in the same execution. I created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1944 to get this fixed.

Answer (score 28):

If you're running the integration tests like this:

```
mvn test-compile failsafe:integration-test
```

Then you should know that according to the [maven documentation on failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/):

> The Failsafe Plugin will not fail the build during the integration-test phase, thus enabling the post-integration-test phase to execute.

I was able to get the build to fail like this:

```
mvn test-compile failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify
```

And here's my failsafe configuration for reference:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just changed the list of goals to run when integration testing, to add `failsafe:verify` as you suggest, and it worked as intended: FAILURE result instead of SUCCESS. That was the step missing to get it to work.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Only `failsafe:verify` is *designed* to cause the build to fail on integration test failure.

Comment: Also, a mere `mvn verify` will produce the expected result as well.

Comment: @CharneyKaye failsafe:integration-test will only run integration test but not unit test, good for some situations

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that the maven property "maven.test.failure.ignore" is not set to "true" in any of your maven pom.xml files, as it can be the only reason to **not** stop the build after test failure.

Comment: no I do not have any setting like that, I'll accept answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

There is one possible additional reason why it happens. Failsafe verify is looking for test classes and expects them to be in ${project.build.directory}/test-classes - if you have a different setup it will just print "No tests to run." and ends if build success regardless of what the result of integration-test phase was.

You have to set **testClassesDirectory** in plugin configuration :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
    
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <environmentType>${environmentType}</environmentType>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <summaryFile>${project.build.directory}/failsafe-reports/failsafe-summary.xml</summaryFile>
                    <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</testClassesDirectory>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXml}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
```