# Skip Build failure in maven if the integration test fails

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-failsafe-plugin

I want to skip the build failure even if the integration test fails. I am using maven-failsafe for Integration test. I am currently getting the following:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.15:verify (default) on project xxxxx: There are test failures.
```

**Question**: Can I use the following for Maven Failsafe Plugin? I know it works for the Surefire plugin, but not sure for failsafe.

```
-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the same parameter is valid for the `maven-failsafe-plugin`. From the documentation of the [`verify`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html) goal, you can set the [`testFailureIgnore`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) to `true`:

> Set this to true to ignore a failure during testing. Its use is NOT RECOMMENDED, but quite convenient on occasion.
>
> - Type: `boolean`
> - Required: No
> - User Property: `maven.test.failure.ignore`
> - Default: `false`

The corresponding user property is `maven.test.failure.ignore`, which means that setting that property on the command line will ignore tests failure.

Comment: How to make build fail if I am only executing integration-test like so `mvn failsafe:integration-test` . I see BUILD SUCESS even if the integration test fails in above command.

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19138201/337666

Answer (score 4):

The [Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html) documentation for the `verify` goal also provides this option:

> Set this to true to ignore a failure during testing. Its use is NOT RECOMMENDED, but quite convenient on occasion.

The configuration entry is [`testFailureIgnore`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) while the user property is indeed `maven.test.failure.ignore`.

So, running:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

Would indeed ignore test failures as you guessed.