# maven: Cannot get pre-integration-phase to work

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing

I'm trying to get pre and post integration phase to work with maven, to no avail.
My goal is to set up and tear down integration tests by running some binaries that are necessary. I'm testing with `antrun-plugin` and `exec-plugin`, but none of them prints the messages.

I'm running `mvn verify`. If I bind the  plugins to `clean` phase and run `mvn clean`, the echo message and the `ls` are shown.

What's wrong? I'm using maven3

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>ls</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-la</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xxx</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo>Cleaning deployed website</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>

                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: nope, because of the failsafe plugin

Comment: I don't see anything noticeably wrong here. Can you post the output of `mvn -X verify` to pastebin or github gist or something? That might reveal more.

Answer (score 0):

I helped someone else get the failsafe plugin configured correctly [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949341/944849).  Try explicitly specifying the phases in the failsafe plugin executions.  Not sure why that is needed, as the failsafe plugin docs say the goals are supposed to be bound to correct phases by default - but it seems to be.