# Binding to lifecycle in maven does not work on failsafe and integration-test

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

When trying to get failsafe bound to the lifecycle, nothing is executed at all. I have read [this guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html) and [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947701/failsafe-plugin-wont-run-on-one-project-but-will-run-on-another-why), and according to this information, it should be possible to make maven execute an the goal `integration-test` of failsafe in the `integration-test`, when I specify it in the `build/pluginManagement/plugins`-section in the pom.xml like this:

```xml
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>failsafe-verify</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Unfortunately, this does not force maven to run failsafe:integration-test at all (neither with mvn integration-test nor mvn verify)

But if I try to use failsafe with the plugin-specification like this (from [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing) with added configuration):

```xml
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IT</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

At least maven compile failsafe:integration-test runs. But unfortunately, this does not call pre- and post-integration-test. I am struggeling for this for a while now, and have no clue - it should be bound as it is.

Does anybody know why this happens, or how I can fix it?

Comment: I would assume that you would have to use pre and post integration test yourself. Is there anything in those phases for failsafe. I believed it had only the test phase for execution and verify for collecting results and possibly break the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you did is to define it **only in pluginManagement** but you have to run it really like this. The definition in pluginManagement is good practice to pin the version of the plugin.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Apart from that it's not necessary to give include rules for the [maven-failsafe-plugin cause it has already defaults defined](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) so no need for that.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! The thing with the pluginManagement was one mistake, and for some reason I don't understand, the configuration with the includes was another. But with your version it works.

Comment: The configuration with the includes is simply not necessary but does not really harm in any way but makes your pom larger.