# Maven : Child pom's argline is not applied?

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project. In the child module, failsafe plugin is used for the integration tests run. Some argLines are defined accordingly :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skipAfterFailureCount>1</skipAfterFailureCount>
        <argLine>-Xmx2048M -Xss512M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The problem is when I run the tests as `mvn test` or `mvn integration-test`, the arglines are not applied for the tests from neither the parent pom directory nor the child pom directory, but if I run the tests as `mvn failsafe:integration-test` from both of the directories, the arglines param are applied.

What is the reason behind this ? Is there any way to apply those params when I run the tests with `mvn test` command ? I tried to pass the parameters via command line as `mvn test -Dchild.argline="-Xmx2048M -Xss512M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skipAfterFailureCount>1</skipAfterFailureCount>
        <argLine>${child.argline}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But it didn't work.

Also I tried to bind test and integration-test phases to failsafe integration-test and defined configuration params there, but it didn't work as well..

I set the MAVEN_OPTS accordingly but it didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

The `failsafe` plugin goals are not included in the lifecycle by default. The POM configuration must include it. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949341/944849) for an example. Also ensure that the plugin definition is in the `<plugins>` section, not inside a `<pluginManagement>` element.

As for how to define options in the POM - use the names supplied in the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html). So, to specify `argLine`, add

```
<argLine>...</argLine>
```

in the plugin config. To specify on the command line, note that "User property" for the value you want to set. For the failsafe plugin's `argLine`, the user property is also `argLine`, so on the command line specify

```
-DargLine=...
```

Maven knows nothing about `child.argline` so silently ignores it. Also note, attribute and user property names are case sensitive.

Comment: So, I have added the executions property exactly like the answer that you have mentioned and added <argLine></argLine> to the configuration section, but when I run the mvn:test from the parent pom directory, still the argLine is not applied for the integration test run..

Comment: This is expected. `mvn test` does not run failsafe. it only runs surefire. Try `mvn verify` or `mvn install`. Hint, reading the [Maven lifecycle docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) in detail will be useful if you will be working with Maven often.